# Big O Notation - Find a Function That Represents the Statement

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics

There's an `f(n)` such that `f(n) != O(f(n/2))`

so by the definition of big O notation:
for `f(n) = n^2` the statement is false, because there is a constant c such that `n^2 = c*(n^2/2)`

Which f(n) will work?
My guess is f(n) = 2. is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f(n) = 2` does not work, no, because there is a constant c such that `2 = c*(2/2)`, namely c = 2. The function you're describing is a constant function, which is normally written O(1).

Any function of the form `f(n) = a * n^b` will not work (with the constant `c = 2^b`), but exponential functions will.

If we let `f(n) = k^n`, then we have `O(f(n/2)) = c * f(n/2) = c * k^(n/2) = c * sqrt(k^n)`. Then we could find

```
f(n) < O(f(n/2))
k^n < c * sqrt(k^n)
sqrt(k^n) < c
```

By choosing n large enough, we could always invalidate this inequality; so there is no such c.

To briefly cover some other functions, anything of the form:
`f(n) = n!`
`f(n) = k^(n^n)`
or
`f(n) = (a^n) / (n^b)`
will work, anything of the form
`f(n) = n^a * (log(n))^b`
`f(n) = n^a */ (log(n))^b`
will not work.

anything "approximately" exponential or faster will work, anything "approximately" polynomial or slower will not.